# Updating cookie in client and aware server-side (ASP 3.0)

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, session-variables

Here's the scenario :
I need to isolate session variables of my application when tabbed browsing on IE8.

I'd like to set an ID by tab using SessionStorage. How to access this ID from my ASP script code (server-side) ? Right now I'm using a cookie and reloading the page, but on cookie change and reload my server-code is executing twice...

I'm thinking about read cookie once in first page and then setting this ID in a hidden field, but this would mean I would have to :

1. Manually add this input to the forms in every pages (I cannot use an include file for that)
2. Take the prefix from the querystring

Can someone think in a different approach?
Maybe smthing in jQuery to update cookie via webservices? Could it be possible?

Comment: i used to have a website that had a cart where the owner could save their cart and i used it with a cookie and on the db.
so even if it will be opened somewhere else it will be reachable :-)

what are you trying to do? yes you can have a page to update the cookie and do something on the server on the same time. if it will be jquery it will do that witout refreshing the page

Comment: Quick question; How do you currently determine if the user/page is on a different tab?